# Launch js server on my online server

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express, ovh

I have written a small application with Node/Express Js who just watch change in a folder and when a csv file is paste, the node js app read the csv file and insert some request in my database.

I work in local system but i need to start this small server on my ovh website
But i can't launch node server.js on my ovh website

Do you have any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: No error, just want to launch the command but i don't found where i can do that

Comment: just install node.js on your vps "sudo apt-get install node", then install yours deps "npm install" and finally run your server "node index.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what kind of OVH server hosting do you have ?

### 1. Web hosting

Is it web hosting ? In that case, you can only do PHP, Perl, C and Python (http://pro.ovh.net/infos/). So *you can't have a NodeJS app*. Basically, if you deploy your website with FTP credentials given by OVH, then you are mostly on a Web hosting server.

For example, the following OVH offers are web hosting:

- https://www.ovh.com/fr/hebergement-web/hebergement-perso.xml
- https://www.ovh.com/fr/hebergement-web/hebergement-pro.xml
- https://www.ovh.com/fr/hebergement-web/hebergement-performance.xml

### 2. VPS

But if you have a VPS (it gives you full root acces), you can do any linux command you want, just like you do on your local machine. Basically, you have a VPS when you have a ful root access : you can SSH into your server and do command like `apt-get update && apt-get install nodejs`.

For example, the following OVH offers are VPS hosting:

- https://www.ovh.com/fr/vps/vps-ssd.xml
- https://www.ovh.com/fr/vps/vps-cloud.xml
- https://www.ovh.com/fr/vps/vps-cloud-ram.xml

### 3. Cloud

Same as VPS